# My computer runs fine until it shuts down. Then it needs to be unplugged before it will start again

Tags: power-supply, power, cmos

Once started, it will run fine, for days on end. But once it shuts down, restart after an auto update for instance, it dies. When I try to start the computer, the fans sputter a little, but never get up to speed and nothing ever shows on the screen. The remedy is unplugging the computer and plugging it back in. No time needs to pass, just unplug and plug back in, hit the power button and the computer boots normally.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to try is to check all power supply connectors by unplugging them and plugging again, then boot, reboot and see what happens.

If it doesn't help, get another power supply and try if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen bad Motherboards do this too... You may need to replace it as well...